# How do I find these ProgressBar

Tags: android, android-progressbar, listview-adapter

[image]
I know how to create a list with `View` like the ones shown above. I am attempting to create a downloader and there will be multiple threads downloading at the same time.
These `Thread`s needs to use the `setProgress(..)` of the `ProgressBar`. However, I do not know how I can refer to these progress bars once they have been created using an adapter. And, by extension, the cancel buttons so that I can add listeners to it.

Please help me with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to create `Task` class, which would implement `Runnable` and have a method `getCurrentProgress()`, which would return progress of current task and a method `cancel()` to cancel itself (canceling can be done in any desired way, by raising a flag or any other way). Then you can start a task using ordinary thread (or use AsyncTask, or one of `Executors`) and add your `Task`s to adapter as an item, and then you can display appropriate Views by using

```
Task task = getItem(position);
progressBar.setProgress(task.getCurrentProgress());
```

in your `getView()` method of adapter.

Then when you need to update progress you just need to update progress inside `Task` and call `adapter.notifyDataSetChange()` on the UI thread. What you also need to do is to ensure that your new progress in `Task` instance would be visible from other threads, for this I would suggest you using `AtomicInteger` as progress indicator (because every `AtomicInteger.get()` returns the latest value).

Comment: so `adapter.notifyDataSetChange()` will cause all the `Views` to be refreshed, automatically and thus showing the progress? :)